# How to prevent excessive emails when using Action Mailer

Tags: ruby, web, actionmailer

I've got a site that uses Action Mailer to send transactional emails. One example email is when a user gets a new comment on a piece of content they've posted ("You've received a new comment"). Right now when the user adds a comment, the author gets a comment. This is built into the comments controller. I'm worried that they can be flooded with comments if tons of people add comments.

What is the best practice for how to implement AM in this fashion? Should I be queuing the mail and somehow aggregating them? Are there other relevant gems or parts of AM that do this for me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is old. I should have handled this by saving the events and sending a digest or summary email instead of one-per-reply.